# Why is this std::vector giving runtime error?

Tags: c++, string, stl

```
vector<int> matchingStrings(vector<string> s, vector<string> q) {
        
        vector<int> res;
        map<string, int> mp;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size();i++){
            mp[s[i]]++;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < q.size();i++){
                res[i] = mp[q[i]]; 
        }
        return res;
}
```

Comment: The vector `res` is *empty*. All indexing into it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: while `std::map` internally adds a new element if the key used with `operator[]` doesn't exist, `std::vector` needs to be filled before to use the `operator[]` to get an element.

Comment: When in doubt, extract a [mcve]. Not only is it required for such a question, it helps you understand the issue as well. As a new user here, please also taake the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is you have an empty vector and by writing:

```
res[i];
```

you're trying to access its `i`th element which doesn't exist.
You can **solve** this by using `push_back` on `res` as follows:

```
res.push_back(mp[q[i]]);//you could use emplace_back here instead
```

Also there are 2 advice that i would like to give here:

1. Use `.at()` instead of `[]` on the `std::map` whenever you don't want to create unintentional elements.
2. In this case you can also use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`.

Taking point 2 of the advice into consideration, you could write the above suggested statement as:

```
res.emplace_back(mp[q[i]]); //use .at() only if you don't want to create/add elements into the map and just want to read
```

So the modified code would look like:

```
vector<int> matchingStrings(vector<string> s, vector<string> q) {
        
        vector<int> res;//res is an empty vector
        map<string, int> mp;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size();i++){
            mp[s[i]]++;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < q.size();i++){
                res.emplace_back(mp[q[i]]); //used emplace_back
        }
        return res;
}
```

**Alternative Solution**:

Create `res` to be of a particular size.

```
vector<int> res(q.size());//res has size equal to q's size
```

Now you can use `res[i];` safely and there is **no need** to use `push_back` and `emplace_back`.

So the modified code would look like:

```
vector<int> matchingStrings(vector<string> s, vector<string> q) {
        
        vector<int> res(q.size());//res has size q
        map<string, int> mp;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size();i++){
            mp[s[i]]++;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < q.size();i++){
                res[i] = mp[q[i]]; //res[i] is fine now 
        }
        return res;
}
```

Comment: you could also suggest `emplace_back` if he is using c++ 11 or higher. In addition, always with c++ 11 or higher it could also avoid iterating `q` and `s` using that old style for and instead use a `range-based for`.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper Yeah i have added 2 advice at the end of my answer now, check it(the edited answer) out.

Comment: Another possible solution is to set the size when creating the vector, as in `std::vector<int> res(q.size());`

Comment: i think the porpose was to add new elements in the map so using `std::map::at` he will break the code.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper On the second for loop i don't think the purpose is to add new elements into the map. Anyways, if the purpose is to add new elements then he/she not use `at()` as already written in my first advice as **whenever you don't want to create unintentional elements**.

Comment: @AnoopRana what happen if `q` has elements that there are no in `s`?

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper I haven't looked for any **logical errors** in the program. The advice of using `at()` instead of `[]` was given because i think the OP is a beginner and sometimes accidentally "undetected/unintentional effects" might happen. It was just a reminder. Also, i have removed the use of `at` from my answer in case the OP intentionally used `[]` on the map. The use of `at` is now given as a comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In additional to the answer of @Anoop Rana, i think you could also reduce the effort of coding the given function by using `std::count` (Since c++17).

```
std::vector<int> matchingStrings(const std::vector<string>& s, const std::vector<string>& q) {
    std::vector<int> ret{};
    ret.reserve(q.size());
    for(auto& str: q)
        ret.emplace_back(std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), str));
    return ret;
}
```

Note : Using `const std::vector<string>&` you can avoid copying values while using matchingStrings